# Convert date to UTC in JS

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone

I have input string like `2023-02-02 15:35 CET` and I have to convert this into UTC time.

I'm trying to find a solution for this, but I'm not able to figure out how to convert input string into Date() object in js.

My main problem is that I cannot figure out how to create Date() with timezone. Time-zones can differ and it could be anything like `BST`, `HKT`ect.

Can somebody help how to get UTC time from input string like this?

Comment: Re *I cannot figure out how to create Date() with timezone*. You can't. ECMAScript *Date* objects don't have a timezone. Civil timezone abbreviations like CET are ambiguous and may represent different offsets.

Comment: "BST" - is that "Bangladesh Standard Time", "Bougainville Standard Time", "British Summer Time", or (historically) "British Standard Time"? 

Comment: CET is UTC+1.  You can manually subtract 1 hour after construction of the time.
Or you can use date-fns: zonedTimeToUtc('2023-02-02', 'UTC')

Answer (score -1):

to convert your date to UTC you can use the `.toUTCString()` method.

```
var inputDate = "2023-02-02 15:35 EST";
var date = new Date(inputDate);
var dateUTC = date.toUTCString();
console.log(dateUTC);
```

Comment: `EST` is working without problem, but other timezones like `CET`, `BST` is not working with this. I have edited my question to show this

Comment: "2023-02-02 15:35 EST" is not a format supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. Safari at least treats it as an invalid date.